# Swift filter array element if subarray contains X

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array composed in this way:

```
[ name, surname,gender, age, city, street, [Sons]]
```

Sons is a subarray where there will be element like:

```
[name , surname, gender, age]
```

I would like to get only person that has  a male son but I'm really stuck.   I actually have no problem in filter main level with code:

```
self.tempArr = self.tempArr.filter({ $0?.city == "new york" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to put all the information into the array? Why don't you create special struct / protocol for a person?

```
struct Person: Hashable {

    enum Gender: Hashable {

        case female
        case male
        case unknown
    }

    let children: [Person]
    let gender: Gender
    let name: String
}

let child = Person(children: [], gender: .male, name: "C")
let array = [
    Person(children: [], gender: .female, name: "A"),
    Person(children: [child], gender: .male, name: "B"),
]
let filtered = array.filter({ $0.children.contains(where: { $0.gender == .male }) })
```

edit:

```
let filtered = array
    .filter({ $0.children.contains(where: { $0.gender == .male }) })
    .filter({ $0.children.contains(where: { $0.name == "A" || $0.name == "B" }) })
```

Comment: this is working really great!!!   thanks!     could I also ask you how to get son who's name start with "A" or "B" (just as example) ?

Comment: Sure. Check the edit. Btw, there are plenty of ways to filter. Read more about the swift arrays and ways to modify them.